# Order a website's content based on its social share count (fb+ twitter + gplus)

Tags: python, django

I've a requirement for my django website.

Is there any way to order contents of my website based on its fb likes + twitter share count + gplus count + etc..

Any api's that I can use.

I saw this feature on the new digg site. They seem to have aggregated the counts fb + twitter + digg) for the stories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript, if you don't have to do it on the backend.

Just read the facebook likes using the API, and sort the divs.